# Angular2 disagnostic example in forms tutorial

Tags: javascript

I can see what this code is doing, but I've not yet run into this syntax within a class.  I've used get {} and set {} property accessors with C# like this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx

However, I was looking over the forms section on Angular.io and ran across something I wasn't familiar with in typescript yet.

```
  // TODO: Remove this when we're done
  get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.model); }
```

What is this `get` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) method, that allows you to represent the object in JSON format by using a pseudo-property called `diagnostic`. So you could then print the object like this:

```
console.log(myObject.diagnostic);
```